# How to install libc++.so in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, c++, libraries, dnf

I wanted to use aapt on my C the error code was:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

With some research I found out that libc++.so was missing

```
ldd aapt

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe30527000)
libc++.so => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f52eface000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f52efac9000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f52ef9eb000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f52ef9e6000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f52ef9c4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f52ef7c2000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f52efc27000)
```

I can’t find a way to install libc++.so in Fedora

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069306/android-sdk-aapt-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libc-so) ?

Comment: Yea, the problem I don't have a libc++.so file to put into /lib64. But I kind of solved it by using aapt2.

Comment: If you solved it, you should post an answer to yourself, wait a day, and mark it as the accepted answer.  It will help people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`libc++.so` is provided by the `libcxx` package. You can install it using `dnf`:

```
dnf install libcxx
```

Comment: I also needed `libcxx-devel`

Comment: Tried this solution using Redhat UBI9 and got: "Error: Unable to find a match: libcxx". Any tips on how to get libc++.so.1 on UBI9?